# JPA Onetomany list not being retreived

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have some JPA code that is causing me some consternation.  There are two objects; a Patient and a PatientUR (identifier) related as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
private List<PatientUR> urs;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH) 
@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
private Patient patient;
```

I can create a patient and patientUR(s) within a transaction and they are persisted correctly.  However, there are occasions (some time later) when I need to retrieve the patientUR(s) from a persisted patient.  I use this approach:

```
// find patient using an initial reference ur
PatientUR myPatientUR = patientURService.find(ur0);  // is there something broken here?
Patient myPatient = myPatientUR.getPatient();

// Modify patient if required

// retrieve all UR's 
List<PatientUR> myRegisteredURList = myPatient.getUrs();
```

The issue is that myRegisteredURList always returns an empty list.  The patient lookup and ur retrieval happens within a transaction.

Not sure what I am missing here?

Just modified the code with:

```
List<PatientUR> myRegisteredURList = patientURService.findByPatient(myPatient);
```

this return correctly - that is searching for PatientUR's by a PatientID rather than by retrieving the PatientUR list from the Patient object.

Comment: have you tried calling any method on the list.. size()?

Comment: try to call myPatient.getUrs() directly after calling myPatientUR.getPatient() and tell me the result. I want to see these modifications

Comment: I have just tried - same result - no entries in list

Comment: yes size() returns '0'

Comment: I have found a solution that works - but still not sure how / why?

Comment: Seem like your ManyToOne configuration is properly. But you should have a look on this working example http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example.html

Comment: it is likely because you are not setting both sides of your bidirectional relationship. If you don’t, you get issues like this, as JPA will not perform any magic to add a reference in the collection for you. JPA allows for caching your java objects, and some providers (eclipselink is one) include a second level cache enabled by default. If you don’t set the reference, it won’t show up unless you reload the entity - by refreshing or otherwise clearing the 2nd level cache. Better to just set both sides of references up front when persisting entities